# Install Glide.js in Rails 6 with Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, glidejs

I created a new Rails 6 project and I'm trying to install the third party javascript library [Glide.js](https://glidejs.com/) via Webpack. However, it seems like I'm missing a crucial step because it's not working.

What I've done so far:

1. Install Glide.js with yarn: `yarn add @glidejs/glide`
2. Require Glide.js in */app/javascript/packs/application.js*:

```
 require("jquery")
 require("@glidejs/glide")
 require("@rails/ujs").start()
 require("turbolinks").start()
 require("@rails/activestorage").start()
 require("channels")

 import "bootstrap"
 import "../stylesheets/application"

 document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

3. Add *javascript_pack_tag* in */app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*:

```html
<head>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
```

When I start the rails server and try to create a Glide object in the web console, I receive the error:

```
> new Glide({})
> ReferenceError: Glide is not defined
```

How can I install Glide.js successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of CommonJS `require` use ES6 `import`

```
import "bootstrap"
import Glide from "@glidejs/glide"
import "../stylesheets/application"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES Modules

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide'

new Glide('.glide').mount()
```

Here's the official doc about setup https://glidejs.com/docs/setup/